Why does NLog not replace the placeholders dynamically if I introduce a wrapper method?
I'm using ASP.NET with NLog.Web at 5.3.8.
This is in a legacy project and I'm not using DI.
I have the following code inside a public class:
private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("WebService");
       
public static void LogError(string message, params string[] args)
{
   Logger.Error(message, args);
}

LogError() is just a wrapper for Logger.Error.
I call it like so:
TestClass.LogError("{A1}, {A2}", "B1", "B1");
However, what gets logged to file is:
2024-04-11 18:12:50.7385|ERROR|TestClass|{A1}, {A2}
Instead of:
2024-04-11 18:12:50.7385|ERROR|TestClass|B1, B1
The placeholders are not getting replaced.
What I've tried:

string.Format()
parameters with integers, e.g. {1}, {2} instead of {A1}, {B1}


I've also just noticed this being highlighted by Resharper:

So could it be that it won't work with params string[] args?

My NLog.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
        <add assembly="NewRelic.LogEnrichers.NLog" />
    </extensions>
    <targets>
        <target name="NewRelicLogFile" 
                xsi:type="File" 
                fileName="{REPLACED}"
                archiveFileName="{REPLACED}"
                archiveNumbering="Date"
                archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
                archiveEvery="Day"
                maxArchiveFiles="30">
            <layout xsi:type="newrelic-jsonlayout">
                <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                <attribute name="level" layout="${uppercase:${level}}" />
                <attribute name="traceId" layout="${activityid:whenEmpty=${mdlc:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}}}" />
                <attribute name="threadId" layout="${threadid}" />
                <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
                <attribute name="errorCode" layout="${event-properties:item=ErrorCode}" />
                <attribute name="errorClass" layout="${exception:format=Type}" />
                <attribute name="errorMessage" layout="${exception:format=Message}" />
                <attribute name="errorStack" layout="${exception:format=StackTrace}" />
                <attribute name="message" layout="${event-properties:item=Message:whenEmpty=${message}}" />
                <attribute name="applicationName" layout="${appdomain:format={1\}}" />
                <attribute name="area" layout="${event-properties:item=Area:whenEmpty=${logger}}" />
            </layout>
        </target>
        <target name="NewRelicLogFile"
                xsi:type="File"
                fileName="{REPLACED}"
                archiveNumbering="Date"
                archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
                archiveEvery="Day"
                maxArchiveFiles="30">
            <layout xsi:type="newrelic-jsonlayout">
                <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                <attribute name="level" layout="${uppercase:${level}}" />
                <attribute name="traceId" layout="${activityid:whenEmpty=${mdlc:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}}}" />
                <attribute name="threadId" layout="${threadid}" />
                <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
                <attribute name="errorCode" layout="${event-properties:item=ErrorCode}" />
                <attribute name="errorClass" layout="${exception:format=Type}" />
                <attribute name="errorMessage" layout="${exception:format=Message}" />
                <attribute name="errorStack" layout="${exception:format=StackTrace}" />
                <attribute name="message" layout="${event-properties:item=Message:whenEmpty=${message}}" />
                <attribute name="applicationName" layout="${appdomain:format={1\}}" />
                <attribute name="area" layout="${event-properties:item=Area:whenEmpty=${logger}}" />
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="NewRelicLogFile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>


Maybe you are using ${message:raw=true} in the NLog Target Layout ? Maybe update the question with your NLog.config-file.

Maybe the solution is the following: Logger.Error(message, (object[])args);

Thanks for the answer @RolfKristensen. Unfortunately, no luck with trying to cast it to object[]. I posted my NLog.config in the description.

Template message for structured logging should (must?) be constant. So you can't do like this.

I think you are right, @AlexanderPetrov. My wrapper can accept params string[] args of any length. It could be only one for instance. The number of placeholders ( in { }), however, is set to expect strictly two parameters. If I pass the param array with only one element, then that's no wonder that it has issues making the substitution.
